# Using nuxt.js google recaptcha module

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, recaptcha, nuxtjs

There is a problem that is wasting too much time. I installed the Nuxt js recaptcha module. but the information given in the documentation is insufficient. I haven't used recaptcha before. How exactly should I use it.

> ```
> <template>
>   <div class="mx-auto mt-5" style="width: 500px; max-width:90%">
>     <div class="mx-auto mt-5" style="width: 230px;">
>       <img
>         src="@/assets/media/images/site/logo.png"
>         style="width: 110px"
>       />.com'a Üye Olun
>     </div>
>     <div class="bg-white p-4 mt-2" style="border-radius:20px">
>       <b-form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" @reset="onReset" v-if="show">
>         <b-form-group id="input-group-2" label-for="input-2">
>           <b-form-input
>             id="input-2"
>             class="form-control form-control-lg"
>             v-model="form.userFullName"
>             placeholder="İsim soyisim"
>             required
>           ></b-form-input>
>         </b-form-group>
>         <b-form-group id="input-group-2" label-for="input-2">
>           <b-form-input
>             id="input-5"
>             class="form-control form-control-lg"
>             v-model="form.userName"
>             placeholder="Kullanıcı adı"
>             required
>           ></b-form-input>
>         </b-form-group>
>         <b-form-row>
>           <b-col>
>             <b-form-input
>               id="input-1"
>               v-model="form.userEmail"
>               type="email"
>               class="form-control form-control-lg"
>               placeholder="E-mail adresiniz"
>               required
>             ></b-form-input>
>           </b-col>
>           <b-col>
>             <b-form-input
>               id="input-3"
>               v-model="form.userPassword"
>               class="form-control form-control-lg"
>               placeholder="Şifreniz"
>               required
>             ></b-form-input>
>           </b-col>
>         </b-form-row>
>
>         <b-form-group
>           id="input-group-4"
>           class="mt-3"
>           v-slot="{ ariaDescribedby }"
>         >
>           <b-form-checkbox-group
>             v-model="form.checked"
>             id="checkboxes-4"
>             :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby"
>           >
>             <b-form-checkbox class="text-dark" value="1"
>               >Beni Hatırla</b-form-checkbox
>             >
>           </b-form-checkbox-group>
>         </b-form-group>
>
>         <b-button
>           :disabled="isClickSubmit"
>           type="submit"
>           class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block"
>           variant="primary"
>         >
>           <b-spinner v-if="isClickSubmit" small style="margin-bottom:3px" type="grow"></b-spinner>
>           Kaydol</b-button
>         >
>       </b-form>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </template>
> ```

> ```
> import axios from "axios";
> export default {
>   layout: "default",
>   data() {
>     return {
>       isClickSubmit: false,
>       form: {
>         userEmail: "",
>         userFullName: "",
>         userName: "",
>         userPassword: null
>       },
>       show: true
>     };
>   },
>   methods: {
>     async mounted() {
>       try {
>         const bune = await this.$recaptcha.init();
>         console.log(bune);
>       } catch (e) {
>         console.log(e);
>       }
>     },
>     async onSubmit(event) {
>       this.isClickSubmit = true;
>       this.onReset();
>       try {
>         console.log(this.$recaptcha);
>         const token = await this.$recaptcha.execute("login");
>         console.log("ReCaptcha token:", token);
>         //  await this.$recaptcha.reset()
>         const form = this.form;
>
>         const sonuc = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/users", {
>           form
>         });
>         this.isClickSubmit = false
>       } catch (error) {
>         console.log("Login error:", error);
>       }
>
>       //   console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form));
>     },
>
>     onReset() {
>       this.form.userEmail = "";
>       this.form.userFullName = "";
>       this.form.userName = "";
>       this.form.userPassword = null
>     }
>   }
> };
> ```

nuxt.config.js:

> env: {
> GOOGLE_SECRET: '...'   },
>
> privateRuntimeConfig: {
> secretKey: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET },
>
> modules: [
>
> ```
> [
>   "@nuxtjs/recaptcha",
>  {
>    siteKey:process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET ,
>    version: 3,
>  }    ]
> ```
>
> ],

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have the recaptcha element in your template.

```html
<!-- Add this where you want the captcha, regardless of version -->
<recaptcha @error="onError" @success="onSuccess" @expired="onExpired" />

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isClickSubmit: false,
            form: {
                userEmail: "",
                userFullName: "",
                userName: "",
                userPassword: null,
                token: null
            },
            show: true
        };
    },
    methods: {
        onSuccess(token) {
            this.form.token = token;
        },
        onExpired() {
            this.$recaptcha.reset();
        },
        onError(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Before you make your request, you'll need to send some things to Google. You'll make this call before serving any requests. This function is from a project of mine.

```js
// Backend code
function Recaptcha(token, ip, callback) {
    axios.post(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${SECRET_KEY}&response=${token}`,
        {
            remoteip: ip,
        },
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':
                    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            },
        },
    )
    .then(callback);
}
```

Example usage of Recaptcha function:
[image: Example usage of Recaptcha function]

Hopefully this helps you understand it a bit better.

Comment: I disabled the recaptcha token verification. theoretically I was sure that I was like this, but since I was a beginner at syntax, I couldn't. I will report the result when I try your suggestion insha'Allah

Comment: upvoted! where exactly are you supposed to call your backend /login endpoint? would you call it from recaptchaSuccess handler but what about form submit for your login form? isnt that a separate callback?